# HttpContext is NULL

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, httpcontext

HttpContext.Current is null on a callback or when on a different thead. How do i get around this. 
I have seen few examples where they say

```
LocalDataStoreSlot slot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("SlotName");
 return (HttpContext)Thread.GetData(slot);
```

It doesnt work.. and honestly it didnt make much sense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't work (evaluates to `null`) because `HttpContext.Current` is *thread local*

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to pass the HttpContext object into what ever you start the thread with:

e.g.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        state =>
        {
            var context = (HttpContext)state;
            //do your stuff here
        },
    HttpContext.Current);
```

Martin

Comment: Could also use a closure. (I prefer closures in most cases, for consistency if nothing else.)

Comment: I have a wrapper for HttpContext public static WebContext Current
        {
            get
            {
                
                if (context.Items[MyContextKey] == null)
                {
                    lock (padlock)
                    {
                        instance = new WebContext();
                        context.Items[MyContextKey] = instance;
                    }
                }

                return context.Items[MyContextKey] as WebContext;
            }
        }

Comment: This WebContext is used everywhere in the code. and as expected this is not working when using threads or CacheItemRemovedCallBack...